# GitLab new branch add connection time out

Tags: gitlab

I want to pull my local project to the company's GitLab with building a new branch, the project is pull by master and could be found in the GitLab but marked as "add connection time out". The status in GitLab shows below:

```
 dev_180703_collectionID   merged  Merge Request  Compare  Light Merge
           d364f533 · add connection time out  · 3 months ago.
```

However, it cannot be checked out by tortoise locally, could anyone advise me what's wrong? is there any problem with my pub_ssh_key or something else? It would be very appreciated if you could help me out.